# python read and rewrite values per row

Tags: python, url-rewriting, line

I am changing an old question of mine.
I have a file with this format; 4 values per line:

```
2623    831     6892    0
2353    1803    3425    0
1910    1823    3810    0
1637    1287    2811    0
2803    546     6609    0
1591    2157    2367    0
2167    1906    2665    0
3192    2168    8362    0
3903    1465    2011    0
2355    1801    2004    0
2390    796     5055    0
1703    1044    3441    0
1886    1328    2731    0
1496    1277    3074    0
1827    460     5992    0
1945    1785    2065    0
1983    1963    2818    0
1532    2229    6936    0
2449    5972    1918    0
2699    2007    1581    0
```

and I want to get this one; 10 values per line:

```
2623    831     6892    0 2353    1803    3425    0 1910    1823    
3810    0 1637    1287    2811    0 2803    546     6609    0
1591    2157    2367    0 2167    1906    2665    0 3192    2168    
8362    0 3903    1465    2011    0 2355    1801    2004    0
2390    796     5055    0 1703    1044    3441    0 1886    1328    
2731    0 1496    1277    3074    0 1827    460     5992    0
1945    1785    2065    0 1983    1963    2818    0 1532    2229    
6936    0 2449    5972    1918    0 2699    2007    1581    0

with open("Read_file") as f1:
       with open("Write_file"),"w") as f2:
            f2.writelines(itertools.islice(f1, 4, None))
```

Any tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('data.txt') as fp, open('output.txt', 'w') as fw:
    data = fp.read().replace('\n', ' ').split()
    for i in range(0, len(data) // 10):
        fw.write(' '.join(data[i * 10: (i + 1) * 10]) + '\n')
```

**Output:**

```
2623 831 6892 0 2353 1803 3425 0 1910 1823
3810 0 1637 1287 2811 0 2803 546 6609 0
1591 2157 2367 0 2167 1906 2665 0 3192 2168
8362 0 3903 1465 2011 0 2355 1801 2004 0
2390 796 5055 0 1703 1044 3441 0 1886 1328
2731 0 1496 1277 3074 0 1827 460 5992 0
1945 1785 2065 0 1983 1963 2818 0 1532 2229
6936 0 2449 5972 1918 0 2699 2007 1581 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A version that does not rely on reading the whole file into memory:

```
def get_words(f):
    for line in f:
        for word in line.split():
            yield word

def chunk_values(iterator, num):
    while True:
        yield [next(iterator) for _ in range(num)]

with open('input.txt') as fin, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:        
    for chunk in chunk_values(get_words(fin), 10):
        fout.write(' '.join(chunk) + '\n')
```